# SQL query for join concatenation and searching within data (wildcard)

Tags: sql

How can I write the SQL query for this particular case?

List details that managers have bought the currency of British pound and Japanese Yen in second half year of 2014. These details include manager’s name, currency name, quantities purchased, exchange rate and transaction date.

Results should be like this

```
FirstName  LastName  CurrencyName  QuantityPurchased  ExchangeRate  TransactionDate
```

The tables I am using are

**Currency**

```
code   name   InterestRate   AnalystID   RatingID
```

**Manager**

```
ManagerID   FirstName   LastName   Qualification   StaffID
```

**Trade**

```
TradeID   Quantities   TradeMode   ExchangeRate   TransactionDate   ManagerID   (Currency)Code  PortfolioID
```

WHAT I understand so far is that I have to use the join function and date range for transaction but don't understand how to search data for British pound while in my table the name of currency is great British pound

actually i have to write an sql query which i am going to run on access
**query**
List details that managers have bought the currency of British pound and Japanese Yen in second half year
of 2014. These details include manager’s name, currency name, quantities purchased, exchange rate and
transaction date. 
and results will be like i mentioned above

Comment: _Sql_ is quite generic. Is it SQL server, MySQL, Oracle... (or any other dbms)?

Comment: actually i have to write an sql query for following

Answer (score 0):

Use a `where` clause and filter by the `name` column in `Currency` like so:

```
WHERE Currency.name IN ('great British pound', 'Japanese yen')
```

Attach this to the rest of your query and it will filter out the currencies other than British pounds and Japanese yen.

Comment: this is helpfull . i want to know how i concatenate strings i tried this FirstName & '' & LastName AS fullName while using SELECT but it is not working .HOW CAN I CONCATENATE WHILE USING BULK OF OTHER FUNCTIONS AS WELL     Thnx in advance

Comment: You still haven't added a tag for which RDBMS you're using (like MySQL, SQL Server, etc.)... String concatenation will be done differently depending on which one you're working with.